# How to recover lost apps after Pepper robot update

Tags: nao-robot, pepper

I have updated my Pepper robot after having installed some new applications from https://cloud.aldebaran-robotics.com/

After rebooting it, it lost many of its apps as the extra language module it had on it.

I fixed the language module problem. But I have no way of finding the old apps that were installer on it prior to the update.

I had performed a backup before, but restoring that backup file didn't bring back the apps.

What can I do to recover all the apps it had?

EDIT: I think I figured were the real problem lies; apps can be installed from the cloud through the robot-linked account; hence I had to change the account associated to Pepper to be able to install the apps from the cloud (because I didn't have the password of the old associated account). And since apps are linked to that account, then changing it would have made me lose the ones the old account had.

What I need to do is regain access to the old account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem.

I had to call the company that sold us the robot, then grant them administrator rights through https://cloud.aldebaran-robotics.com/ so that they remade the installation on their end.

Just be extra careful by keeping a backup of your apps on your PC before changing the admin of your robot, because everything is reset to zero : languages and apps.